# Track position in array despite manipulation (sort, remove, insert)

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table

Let's say I've got an array of tables. Further, let's say I've altered it in some way. After every manipulation I could do the following:

```
for index,element in ipairs(elements)
    element.position = index;
end
```

This should allow me to know the position of the element, but it seems wasteful.

Is there a right way, or at least a less silly way, to be doing this?

Comment: The question is what is your goal here. Why do you want to store the index in the array of the element inside the element itself? What do you intend to do with that information there?

Comment: It's hard to explain without sharing all my code (which isn't that long, but it's for an application, and I don't want to cheat). I'll think about how to make the question clearer.